# Yet another repainting issue in my JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

I'm learning Java and testing a simple note taking program. I have a panel that is hidden at startup, and made visible by the click of a button. But I can't see this panel until I resize the window of the program ! I sincerely tried everything I could find online here and there, and still didn't manage to get it running properly. Here is the code :

```
//Main JFrame "Fenetre"
//imports
...

public class Fenetre extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel west = new JPanel();
    private CEPan CEPan = new CEPan();
    private JPanel container = new JPanel();
    private JSplitPane split = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, west, CEPan);
    private JButton nouvelleNote = new JButton("Nouvelle note");

    public Fenetre() {
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 700));
        this.setTitle("Notes");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setContentPane(container);
        container.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        west.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 700));
        west.add(nouvelleNote);
        nouvelleNote.addActionListener(this);
        CEPan.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 700));
        CEPan.setBackground(Color.RED);

        split.setDividerSize(4);
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        container.add(split, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //At first this panel is hidden until the click of the button
        CEPan.setVisible(false);

        this.setContentPane(container);
    }


    public void nouvelleNote() {
        CEPan.setVisible(true);
        container.repaint();
        west.repaint();
        this.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        nouvelleNote();
    }

}
```

### `CEPan`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class CEPan extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private TextArea titleTF = new TextArea(35);
    private TextArea contentTA = new TextArea(16);
    private JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(contentTA, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    private JScrollPane scrollTitle = new JScrollPane(titleTF);
    public boolean hide;

    public CEPan() {        
        titleTF.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(scrollTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        titleTF.setEditable(true);

        contentTA.setLineWrap(true);
        scrollTitle.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    }
}
```

### `TextArea`

```
public class TextArea extends JTextArea {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Color couleur = new Color(1, 168, 135);

    public TextArea(int fs) {
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, fs);
        this.setFont(font);
        this.setForeground(couleur);
        //this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
    }
}
```

### `Notes`

```
public class Notes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fenetre fenetre = new Fenetre();
        fenetre.pack();
        fenetre.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `public class TextArea extends JTextArea {` This is a confusing name for the class, given there is a `java.awt.TextArea`. Further, a factory method would be better to produce the text areas.

Comment: Just calling `repaint()` on the root object will repaint all of its children, so `nouvelleNote()` should only call `this.repaint()` or even better `repaint()` as the `this` is implied

Comment: *"I  have a panel that is hidden at startup, and made visible by the click of a button."* Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: @AndrewThompson has the best solution, but another option would be to call `revalidate()` alongside `repaint()` when adding or removing `Component`s or `JComponent`s

Comment: Thanks to all for the usefuls comments. It turned out that the problem wasn't exactly about resizing the window. It was only OK when I resized the right side of the window, more precisely the CEPan. It was only when the Divider was dragged even a millimeter that the CEPan appeared. I still don't understand the problem but I was able to patch it only by instanciating the JSplitPanel when the button is clicked, otherwise I only have the "west" panel alone with the button

Comment: Based on your example, `CEPan` is never added to anything.  If you need to dynamically update the UI at runtime, then you will need to call `revalidate` followed by `repaint` to trigger a layout and paint pass - Also, beware, that most layout managers don't calculate the size of hidden components during a layout pass, this may mean that your window is initially to small to support it

Answer (score 0):

When a `JComponent` has already been displayed and some event causes a modification of such JCompoment, the best way to avoid problems is to always call `repaint()` and `revalidate()` on the involved component. The first method causes the component to be repainted in order to show any change involving the components look (e.g change a color), the second one notifies the layout manager to recalculate the layout, as it is necessary if some component has been added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one line of code: `resize(900,700)` after you make your `CEPan` visible.

```
`public void nouvelleNote() {
   CEPan.setVisible(true);
   resize(900, 700);
 }`
```

This would resize your JFrame and then it will automatically repaint and revalidate all of the components.

Answer (score -2):

I've had this problem before. All you need to replace all `repaint` method calls with:

```
yourJFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Eg.:

```
public void nouvelleNote() {
    CEPan.setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Even if the frame is already visible this method will reassure that everything is rendered correctly.